# What kind of themes can I use on Xfce?

Tags: themes, xfce

I don't like the themes I have in my system (Xubuntu 11.04) by default.

- Is [Xfce Look](http://xfce-look.org/) the only place where I can get new themes?
- Can I run themes that are made for Gnome, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use gtk2 themes from [Gnome-Art](http://art.gnome.org/themes/gtk2) as well.

Similar websites:

1. [deviantARTs](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/linuxutil/xfce/?alltime=yes#order=9): XFCE-section
2. [Customize.org](http://customize.org/xfce): XFCE-section
3. [XFCE-Forums](http://forum.xfce.org/index.php?board=9.0): mostly window manager themes
4. [deviantARTs](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/linuxutil/gnome/gtk2/?alltime=yes#order=9): (GNOME) GTK2-section

[source](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes)

### Example install from Gnome-Art

First create a `.themes` folder in your home folder

```
mkdir ~/.themes
```

Download one of the themes e.g. Aero-ion which should be saved in your `~/Downloads` folder

then extract the compressed tar file into `.themes`

```
cd ~/.themes
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/GTK2-AeroIon.tar.gz
```

Finally Settings Manager - Appearance to apply your new theme e.g. AeroIon will appear at the top of the list.

Here is my example:

[image]

Comment: Looks like download links on Gnome Art are broken (at least the ones I tried were)...

Answer (score 1):

The excellent Faenza icons work not only with Gnome, but with XFCE as well.

They are easy to install through a [PPA on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox).

Issue the following commands in a terminal window to install the icons, then select them in `Menu > Settings > Settings Manager > Appearance > Icons`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

[image: Faenza theme]

Also, have a look at [xfce-look.org](http://xfce-look.org).

Answer (score 0):

Another nice effect can be achieved by replacing the default Sans font in GTK+ menus with a compacter, crisp and more readable font. An excellent substitute is the freely available Adobe [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro).

I find it most convenient to install new fonts using Font Manager.

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

After downloading and extracting the font, click on the cogwheel button and then on `Install Fonts`.

Finally, navigate to `Menu > Settings > Settings Manager > Appearance > Fonts` and make sure to select the Source Sans Pro **Regular** variant. You may also want to increase the font size one notch. For consistency, you may set the same font as the default font in your browser.

Here is how [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) looks like.

[image: Source Sans Pro glyphs]

Answer (score 0):

If a XFCE theme pleases you in design, but not in colour, you can edit it for all users.
For example, I changed a number of hex-coded RGB colours in the default Greybird XFCE theme with a text editor.

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Answer (score 0):

At [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+For+Xfce+%26+LXDE?content=146674)  you can also find themes for Xfce4