# launching apps that aren't showing up in the app finder (Xubuntu on VM)

Tags: xubuntu, software-center, customization

I've been playing around with running different distros of Linux in VirtualBox on my iMac (OS 10.7.3). This is the first time I've used Linux so I basically don't know what I'm doing, and am learning as I go (googling stuff constantly.) Please keep this in mind when answering - I want to learn, but don't assume I know anything already!

Currently I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox, and I wanted to be able to customize the theme a bit more, so I downloaded '**Appearance**' and '**Unity Tweak Tool**' from the themes and tweaks tab of the software centre.

The problem is, they haven't turned up in the App Menu or App Finder. The apps ARE showing up in the 'installed' tab of the software centre, but you don't seem to be able to launch them from there, so the only way I can launch them is in Terminal.

After finally discovering the files in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, I typed the path `/var/cache/apt/archives/[filename]` into terminal and hit enter. It said `no such file or directory found`. Did I do something wrong? Is there any other way around this issue of apps not showing in the app menu?

Comment: Nope, `/var/cache/apt/archives` is system folder, you should not touch it. Proper commands are `gnome-control-center` and `unity-tweak-tool`.

Comment: and what do I do with them? sorry if this sounds like an idiotic question, but I really am completely new to this, so I need the command lines explained to me in full.

Comment: Run them in terminal.

Comment: If you open the menu editor in the Settings manager (available from the Applications menu) do those apps appear? If they are unchecked, check them, so they appear

Comment: Keep in mind, that Unity Tweak Tool is completely useless if you aren't running Unity. Xubuntu per default uses Xfce instead of Unity, so it'll not do anything for you ;-) Appearance is probably the Gnome tool, so it will only have effects if you use Gnome instead of Xfce.

Comment: very good point, soulsource! Just checked and Appearance is actually for Unity also. Do you know if there is an equivelant tool for Xfce? And no, they don't turn up in the menu editor...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content of your question, I'm assuming your intent is to customize xfce. There are a number of good sources for this information. If I'm wrong, please downvote and comment to give me an idea where I went wrong and what I can do to help!

There's a nice answer regarding custom Ubuntu XFCE themes heer at [What kind of themes can I use on Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53437/what-kind-of-themes-can-i-use-on-xfce)

If your looking for more eyecandy for xfce look [here](http://xfce-look.org/)

If your looking for more basic customization look on [this page](http://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-xfce-desktop/) or [this one](http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osDesktopConfigXfce.php)

Conversely, if you find this info helpful please accept/upvote